# error: mclmcr.h: No such file or directory calling matlab function from C

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I am trying to use Matlab user defined function from C++. I have created library using below command.

mcc -B csharedlib:libMyLib myFunction.m

It does not creates mclmcr.h and libmwmclmcrrt.so. I wonder does it a part of runtime library?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/c-shared-library-target.html#bsic1of-1):

> All application and software components generated by MATLAB Compiler
>   and the associated builder products need to link against only one
>   MathWorks library, mclmcrrtxx.lib

The .lib and the corresponding header files can be found in `$matlabroot/extern`, while the .dll/.so shared libraries can be found in `$matlabroot/runtime/$arch` (or inside the MCR installation)

MATLAB has a convenient function [`mbuild`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/mbuild.html) (you have to set it up once using `mbuild -setup`). [`mbuild`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/c-shared-library-target.html#f2-1005105) knows how to invoke the C/C++ compiler with the correct switches so the compiler can find the required include files and libraries. You can use `mbuild` to create your own executables and link them with MATLAB Compiler-generated shared libraries.

For example, it would be called inside MATLAB as:

```
>> mbuild testProgram.c -I./distrib -L./distrib -llibMylib
```

to build a program that links against the C shared library you generated using the MATLAB Compiler, where `distrib` directory contains those generated files.

Some other references:

- [Set MCR Paths for Development and Testing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/mcr-path-settings-for-development-and-testing.html)
- [Set MCR Paths for Run-Time Deployment](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/mcr-path-settings-for-run-time-deployment.html)